# Add SSL optional on some URLs

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, apache2, vhosts, apache2.4

I am using Apache 2 for a web app.

I want to force SSL for most URLs. e.g. If I go to `http://example.com/foo` I will be redirected to `https://example.com/foo`.

This is easy enough by using:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RedirectMatch ^(/.*)$ https://example.com$1
</VirtualHost>
```

However, I want SSL to be optional for any url that has this pattern:

```
example.com/api/*
```

The reason being is that my mobile app is already live and uses the http version of the website, and I don't wish to break it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precede the RewriteRule with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/
```

Comment: I have the following code: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/
        RewriteRule ^(/.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]`, but when I go to `http://example.com/api/offer/feed`, it redirects to `http://example.com/index.php`. Why is it doing this?

Comment: Unrelated rule?

Comment: The only other rules are found in the [default Laravel htaccess file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.1/public/.htaccess). I'm really confused in how to solve this issue as I need it solved urgently!

Comment: When I remove the htaccess file it works fine. But I don't understand why this behaviour is happening. Is this a bug with Apache?

Comment: I accepted the answer as it's correct. My issue with the htaccess file will be put in another question

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42695014/apache-2-rewrite-rule-is-incorrectly-changing-the-url