# Apache 2 rewrite rule is incorrectly changing the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

*Note this is a repeat of a previous question I have asked. However it was initially badly worded and was edited so many times it almost became a different question, hence I decided to make a new question*

### Files

I have the following files:

**example.dev.conf vhost file**

This is a very simple vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.dev
        ServerAlias *.example.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example

        <Directory /var/www/example >
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.dev
        ServerAlias *.example.dev 
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example

        <Directory /var/www/example >
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**.htaccess**

The following file redirects all urls to the https equivalent, unless it starts with `/api/`.

It should also makes sure that ALL routes uses the `index.php` controller.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

### The Problem

This works for the most part.

For example `http://example.dev/blah` redirects to `https://example.dev/blah`

However, it does not seem to work as expected for anything that starts with `/api/`.

For example: `http://example.dev/api/blah` redirects to `https://example.dev/index.php`, when it should have not done a redirect at all!

Note that the redirects work fine if I remove the final 3 lines of the htaccess file.

### How to replicate?

I have found that some people found it difficult to replicate my problem and have insisted there is some other rule somewhere. Hence I decided to show ALL my steps the best I can so it's very easy to replicate:

```
vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
vagrant up --provider virtualbox
vagrant ssh

sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo a2enmod rewrite

cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
sudo touch example.dev.conf   
# copy contents of the example.dev.conf vhost file as seen above
sudo a2ensite example.dev.conf

cd /var/www/
sudo mkdir example
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/example
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/example
cd example
echo "test" > index.php
touch .htaccess
# Copy contents of .htaccess file as seen above

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/example
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/example

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I managed to figure out the issue.

Upon reading this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l it turns out the last flag doesn't necessarily mean no further rules are used.

For example, for the following file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=308]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

- `/api/blah` is rewritten to `index.php`
- It then goes through all the rules again. According to the documentation, this can happen for the following reasons:

> It is possible that as the rewritten request is handled, the .htaccess file or  section may be encountered again, and thus the ruleset may be run again from the start. Most commonly this will happen if one of the rules causes a redirect - either internal or external - causing the request process to start over.

- `index.php` then matches the first rule so a redirect to `https://example.dev/index.php` is created.

The solution is to instead use the [END flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end) (which as @anubhava mentioned, is only supported in Apache 2.4+), to prevent the rules being re-processed.

So the solution is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [END]
```

Now when I go to `http://example.dev/api/blah`:

- It is rewritten to `index.php`
- As it has the `END` rule, the rules are not processed again!
- Therefore `http://example.dev/api/blah` stays where it is and uses the `index.php` controller as desired.

Thanks @Olaf Dietsche for getting me to the right track and suggesting the 308 redirect!

Answer (score 2):

Both other answers are good but I am posting another for these 3 reasons:

1. [Answer from Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42695256/548225): It will work for all the cases except when user directly enters `http://domain.con/index.php` in the browser. As per requirements anything except when starting with `/api/` should be redirected to `https://
2. [Answer from Yahya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42698638/548225): `END` flag is only supported in Apache 2.4+ so this answer won't work for someone on Apache 2.2 facing similar answer.
3. `POST` requests should be redirected with `307/308` otherwise post data will be lost (See Olaf's helpful comment below).

To make it work for both these cases I suggest using `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` because `REQUEST_URI` changes to `/index.php` after last rule execution.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+api/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=308,NE]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: What if I also want to forward the post data to HTTPS?

Comment: For this, you have status codes [`307`/`308`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#307). Although these are only available for HTTP/1.1

Comment: Thanks so much @OlafDietsche for answering this query from Yahya. Yes change `R=301` to `R=308` for preserving `POST` data. Most of the moden browsers support `HTTP/1.1`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the reason for `/api/` requests being redirected to `https://example.dev/index.php` are the following steps

- rewrite `/api/...` to `index.php`
- redirect `index.php` to `https://...`

To see why this happens, look at how [Ruleset Processing](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html#InternalRuleset) works. The rules are tried in order, but when a rewrite occurs ("URI changed?" in the picture), Apache starts with the resulting URI again, until no further rewrite occurs.

---

To avoid the redirect to `https://...` for `/api/`, you must also exclude `index.php` for the first rule, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: But excluding the api for the second rule means that if I have `http://example.dev/api/blah` it will no longer use my `index.php` controller. Instead it will look for the physical file called `api/blah`, which usually gives a 404 error

Comment: Ok, so you want the rewrite from `api` to `index.php`?

Comment: All urls should still use the `index.php` controller. The only thing I want is to make https optional for anything that starts with  `/api/`, and required for everything else.

Comment: Ok wow I think you got it. But I'm still confused at to why this is happening. When `/api/...` is rewriten to index.php, this is the last rule! `index.php` should not be redirected to `https://...`.